# Determining if an app has quit using XCTest UI tests

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

A certain function in my iOS Swift app will quit the app if the build is deemed to be invalid (out of date etc.).

How do I use XCTest to determine if the app has successfully quit and has returned the simulator to the homescreen?

I've tried the obvious ways like

```
XCTAssertFalse(XCUIApplication().exists, "app should have quit")
```

and

```
XCTAssertFalse(XCUIApplication().enabled, "app should have quit")
```

if I try and do any operations on XCUIApplication it hangs.

Answer (score 1):

You can register an observer in the `NSNotificationCenter` for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and in your tests, if the build is found to be out of date, make a test exception:

```
let expectation = expectationWithDescription("myDescription")

waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10) { error in
}
```

and in your notification handler:

```
func someHandler() {
    expectation.fulfill()
    //unregister the observer
}
```

That way if the notification is posted, the expectation will be fulfilled, otherwise the test will fail. Be sure to only set up this case if the build is outdated, otherwise it will always fail if the notification isn't posted.